# Creating array with Split generates Type Mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I have an inventory list for tools. The point of this program is to search for tools based on tool number entered and based on tool information to locate the corresponding tool file in the specific folder. The name of the files contain part of the tool information.

I loop through the inventory list first, once locating a specific tool, retriving corresponding information and trying to match with the file names within the folder. Here I created another loop to go through the files.

```
Sub openBaseline(tn)

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

Dim intpath As String
Dim path As String

Dim pn As String
Dim ps As String
Dim varr()
Dim partnum As String
Dim toolsize As String
Dim toolnumber As String


Dim i As Integer

'Testing If Me.idBox.Value = "" And Me.beadBox.Value = "" And Me.partBox.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

If tn = "" Then tn = InputBox("Scan or enter tool number.", "Load Baseline", "")
If tn = "" Then Exit Sub

'If Right(Left(tn, 2), 1) <> "-" Then
    'If Len(tn) = 5 Then
        'tn = Left(tn, 1) & "-" & Right(tn, 4)
        'Else:
            'MsgBox "Tool numbers should be in the format of '1-1234'", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
            'Exit Sub
    'End If
'End If
toolnumber = tn
'Debug.Print toolnumber



With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool Log")
        intpath = "H:\PROCESS\PROCESS SAMPLES\SI-Baselines\JSP" 'Switch to \woodbridge.corp etc
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
        Set objFolder = objFSO.getfolder(intpath)
            'For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            'varr = Split(objFile.Name, " ")
            'ReDim Preserve filename(objFolder.Files.count, 2)

        For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row Step 1
        'Debug.Print .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

            Debug.Print .Cells(i, "A")

            If .Cells(i, 1).Text = toolnumber Then
                Debug.Print i
                pn = .Cells(i, 3).Value
                ps = .Cells(i, 4).Value
                Debug.Print pn
                Debug.Print ps
            End If

              'i = 1
            For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
                Debug.Print objFile.Name
                'Debug.Print objFile.path

                varr() = Split(objFile.Name, " ")
                partnum = varr(0)
                toolsize = varr(1)

                Debug.Print partnum
                Debug.Print toolsize

                path = objFile.Name


                'Does not work for family tools
                Select Case toolsize
                Case Is = ps
                    If partnum = pn Then
                        Workbooks.Open filename:=objFile.path, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Case Is = Right(varr(1), Len(varr(1)) - 1)
                    If partnum = pn Then
                        Workbooks.Open filename:=objFile.path, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End Select


              Next objFile

                    'And toolsize = Right(ps, Len(ps) - 1) Then
                    'path = objFile.Name
                    'path = Right(path, Len(path) - Len(pn) - 1)
                    'If Left(path, Len(ps)) = ps Then
                        'Workbooks.Open filename:=objFile.path, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
                        'Exit For
                    'End If
                'End If

                'i = i + 1
            Next i

End With
End Sub
```

It gives a Type mismatch error on line

```
varr() = Split(objFile.Name, " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare you array variable as array of `String` (preferable) or as a single `Variant`, but not as an array of `Variant`

Also, you should omit the brackets when assigning the result of the split-command.

```
Dim varr() as String
' or: Dim varr as Variant
...
varr = Split(objFile.Name, " ")
```