# taking a Custom Number field to Split String giving type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data field that is on the worksheet as a custom number format

geo:
[![![data column example][1]][1]

sum:[![![data column example][2]][2]

I am taking that field and comparing it to wo other fields on another worksheet to determine if this one is in between those. So I've got the below code that uses variants for the arrays and splits along spaces. I think the best way is to use the `datevalue` and `timevalue` functions with inequalities, both of which take strings. any ideas why I'm getting a type mismatch error at the split?

UPDATE: Based on the #### comment, and the column reference mistake, I autosized the dateTime co and changed my column references. Now my `sumfull` string gets the text of the column. I am still getting a type match error on the next line. I've updated the code below. The code breaks at `sumsplit = Split(sumfull, " ")` with a Type mismatch error. The contents of `.Cells(i.row, 4).text` is "01/23/2022 18:53". This is also the value of sumfill when it breaks.

```
Option Explicit

Sub O_face()
Dim geo As Workbook
Dim sum As Workbook
Dim geowks As Worksheet
Dim sumwks As Worksheet

Dim i As Variant
Dim j As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim georng As Range
Dim sumrng As Range
Dim geofull As Date

Dim sumfull As Date
Dim sumfull2 As Date

Set geo = ThisWorkbook
Set sum = Workbooks.Open("MyFile.csv")

Set geowks = geo.Workshets(1)
geowks.Range("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Set sumwks = sum.Worksheets(1)
sumwks.Range("F:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit

lastrow = geowks.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
geowks.AutoFilterMode = False
geowks.Range("A1:L" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues

Set georng = geowks.Range("E2:E" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


lastrow = sumwks.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
sumwks.AutoFilterMode = False
sumwks.Range("A1:P" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues

Set sumrng = sumwks.Range("C2:C" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'have to split the date time cell because it's a custome data type in the worksheet. Then compare the date and time seperately.....
For i = 1 To sumrng.Rows.Count

    sumfull = sumrng.Cells(i, 4)
    sumfull2 = sumrng.Cells(i, 5)

    For j = 1 To georng.Rows.Count
        geofull = georng.Cells(j, -2)
        If sumrng(i, 1) = georng(j, 1) And _
            geofull >= sumfull And geofull >= sumfull2 Then
                sumrng.Cells(i, 15) = "IS THIS WHAT YOU WANT!!!!"
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Dimensioning the arrays before filling them with Split is unnecessary, the variable takes on the array dimensions that are given to it by Split. It shouldnt be causing any errors, but it is a wasted step.

Comment: It's also probably not related to your error, but I suggest testing `IsDate` before doing `DateValue` and `TimeValue`. It avoids future problems, when the input isn't what you expect. Same thing with `sumsplit(1)` and `geosplit(1)`, there is a chance that `Split` doesn't output an array with two elements.

Comment: Doing `CStr(Range.Text)` is redundant, the `.Text` property always returns a String, so there isn't a need to wrap it with `CStr`. Additionally, when you save values into String variables, VBA will automatically attempt to convert to string if the data isnt already a string.

Comment: In the watch window, ```sumfull``` is "900". It's not returning the cell as a literal string, which is I need, right?  why i tried recasting using ```CStr()```. IDK why vba isn't returning the literal string.

Comment: Honestly, I'm a little confused at the objective. If you want to compare dates, you can litterally do `Date1 > Date2` and that will return True or False. You could take `[b2] > [b3]` directly from the excel sheet and VBA will compare the two datevalues for you. You don't need a custom string parse function, VBA knows what Dates are...

Comment: I tried that first. Using ```range.cells()```, or ```range.cells().value``` with the equivalencies both did not find the match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(a)**
`Split` returns an array of strings. You can assign the result to a dynamic String-Array or to a Variant-Variable, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57113178/7599798 . What you try to do is assign it to a Variant *Array* - this will fail. You also don't need to set the dimensions of that array, `split` will take care about that anyhow. So that would be:

```
Dim sumsplit() As String
sumfull = CStr(sumrng.Cells(i.Row, "f").Text) 
sumsplit = Split(sumfull)
```

**(b)**
Assuming that your data in Excel are Dates (not Strings that look like a Date), there is neither a reason to convert them to a string nor split that string to get the date and time part. Just use Date variables. In the background, Dates are Floating point Numbers (=Double). The number before the decimal defines the Date-Part (Days since 31.12.1899), the remainder the Time. To get Date and Time of an Excel-Date:

```
Dim sumfull As Date, fsumdate As Date, fsumtime As Date
sumfull = sumrng.Cells(i.Row, "f").value
fsumdate = int(sumfull)         ' Remove the digits after the decimal
fsumtime = sumFull-int(sumfull) ' The digits after the decimal is the Time.
```

**(c)** I don't fully understand the logic of your If-statement, but you can simply compare date variables with `<` and `>` - a higher number means a later date/time. I assume that you will not need to compare date and time parts separately. Probably this will do:

```
Dim geoDate As Date, fsumDate As Date, lSumDate As Date
fsumDate = sumrng.Cells(i.Row, "f").value
lsumDate = sumrng.Cells(i.Row, "g").value
geoDate  = georng.Cells(j.Row, "b").value

If geodate >= fsumdate And geodate <= lsumdate Then
```

**(d)**
Generally, you should avoid using the `Text`-property. If for any reason the width of a cell is too small to display the date, Excel will display "######" instead - and you will get exact this into your program.

Comment: the dates are not in the worksheet as 'dates'. They are a custom number format so that it displays a more military format with "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm". That's why I am trying to extract the cell as a string, because as far as my limited knowledge goes, there is no DateTime function organic excel.

Comment: I tried casting the arrays as strings. I got the same error. I think the type mismatch is related the the cell data type. trying to be read in as a string. the watch window shows that sumfull is valued at "900" just before the error on the next line.

Comment: Number *formats* are just a rule how a specific value is *displayed*. You can display a date in 1000 different ways - it's *value* stays the same. `900` seems strange to me: Have you checked if you read the correct cell of the correct worksheet?

Comment: @FunThomas OH! I just understood the issue!! `sumrng` DOESN'T START FROM "A" which means `.Cells( row, "g")` DOESN'T GIVE COLUMN G. Since `sumrng` starts from "C", asking for "g" gives the column from "C" that would be "g" if "C" were "A". Which is a confusing way to say, DONT USE COLUMN NAMES!

Comment: @Toddleson: God  catch, wrong conclusion: You will have the same problem when using column numbers: `sumrng.cells(row, 7)` will also return column 9 (`I`). But maybe a little bit less confusing.

Comment: awesome catch! thank you so much! I updated the reference getting the correct string. Still getting a type mismatch error.

Comment: Could you update your question, write down the exact statement and the content of the cell when this happens?

Comment: done. Is that what you're requesting?

Comment: I hate to say it, but you completely missed all 4 points of my post. But if you want to go down that road, it's up to you. That said: As written in point my first point: The result of `Split` is an Array of Strings and you can't assign it to an Array of Variants. Either write  `Dim geosplit() As String` or `Dim geosplit As Variant`, similar for the other variables that get the result of the `Split`-function. But again: You are dealing with Dates, so use them as `Date`. You don't want your code to break only because the format of the cell changes to `dd.mm.yyyy`

Comment: I must have been doing something wrong. I tried casting those cells as dates and it wouldn't take....however, I did it again just now and it works. I'll update the code to the working stuff. Thank you so much!!!!!